# Появление тени блока при прокрутке страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Приветствую.
Как сделать так, чтобы при прокрутке страницы в блока появилась тень? Если же прокрутить в обратную сторону - тень должна исчезнуть. 
Возьмем, например, header (хедер) сайта, который вверху (как на этом сайте). Изначально у него нет тени. Есть только border-bottom и все. Если же прокрутить вниз немного, у хедера появляется тень чтобы немного его выделить.

Как повторить это? Помогите пожалуйста.

P.S. Заметил, что при прокрутке добавляется к хедеру класс _scrolling, но не могу понять как это работает.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

С помощью JQuery можно так

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('header').toggleClass('scroll', $(this).scrollTop() > 100);
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

header {
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.scroll {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <header>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Супер. Спасибо.